Pinescript: Open new trade when previous trade is on entry level
I have developed my own strategy in Pine Script for trading in TradingView.
I use take profit levels that are based on a multiple of the ATR for my exit indicator.
I have implemented a piece of risk management where my Stop Loss is adjusted to a higher level at each take profit. For example, at Take Profit 1 the stop loss moves to the entry price, and at Take Profit 2 the stop loss moves to Take Profit 1.
I do this to secure my profits.
What I want to achieve now is for TradingView to open a new trade as soon as my previous trade is at the entry price or higher.
This way, I can open a new trade without risk because the previous trade can no longer incur a loss.
When I code this, I encounter No volume of the new positions issue.
Weird thing is when i use exit indicators as exit strategy it does work. Only not when i want to implement this on Take Profit Levels
I expect that also the feature works when i use take profits as my exit strategy
